# CGFloat vs Double in SwiftUI Graphics

Tags: swiftui, cgfloat, swiftui-layout

In SwiftUI is there any reason not to replace all instances CGFloat with Double?

Is it less efficient or something?  Does the compiler just change it to CGFloat anyway?

XCode is not complaining when I use Double... but I still see CGFloat used in most all tutorials etc.

Comment: See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.5/interchangeable-cgfloat-double